# Did Eleven’s mother initially have any abilities?

Tags: stranger-things

It’s fairly clear that, as of the “current time” on *Stranger Things*, Eleven’s mother has some weak psychic powers. She can perceive Eleven trying to communicate with her, and make lights go on and off.

Was this a side effect of some experiments performed upon her during her pregnancy (presumably with the goal of producing a powerful psychic, like Eleven)? Or was there some indication that she had these powers previously?